# Why am I seeing two versions of Google Search page?

Tags: google-search

Why am I seeing two versions of Google Search?

**Original Version:**

[image]

**Alternate Version:**

[image]

The latter one is showing up occasionally.

Is this because of a virus or something?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. This doesn't look like the kind of practical, detailed question that we are looking for. Please check out [tour] and [ask].